# Purpose & Tutorial for how we make customized usage of `std::iterator`

Tags: c++

```
class MainClass
{    
    class EmbeddedClass
    {...};

    class const_iterator 
      : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, EmbeddedClass> 
    {...}

    class iterator: public const_iterator
    {...};
};
```

I have seen the above design in a legacy project.

Question 1> What is the main purpose to design an embedded `class const_iterator` and `class iterator`?

Question 2> Is there a good design tutorial that illustrates how we can implement the customized `const_iterator` or `iterator` class in a professional way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1> What is the main purpose to design an embedded class const_iterator and class iterator?

Presumably `MainClass` represents some kind of container, collection, list generator, or other iterable data structure.
Creating iterator classes with those names allows `MainClass` to be used as a container class in the standard algorithms like `std::for_each` or `std::accumulate`.

> Question 2> Is there a good design tutorial that illustrates how we can implement the customized const_iterator or iterator class in a professional way?

I'm not immediately aware of one.